# How to send POST request to SOAP API using HttpClient with Kerberos authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, post, httpclient, kerberos

I have some service, which is SOAP API placed on Windows Server machine protected by Kerberos authentication. I would like to consume this API using .NET Core.
For now I was using some WCF client with basic authentication. So I was using some interface obtained from wsdl and after providing some credentials it was fine. Now I have to switch to Kerberos.

On the server SPN's are configured and I got a keytab file with principals.

As far as I know it is not such a simple case, so I have prepared some shared library in C++ to obtain the negotiate header value (it uses principals from proper keytab). I ve included this library in .net core project using DllImport and everything works fine. I m able to connect to the API, get the negotiate header, as well as obtain the ticket using kinit

`kinit -V HTTP/test.test.com@test.com` works fine.

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFp8j.png)

When I already have the Negotiate header value, I would like to make simple POST request (using httpClient) with proper header value (ticket), but always I got 401 Unaithorized.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "some-type");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "some-type");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Negotiate XYZAA....."
    // ...
}
```

As a body I send simple SOAP envelope which is fine.

Should I store something more just after obtaining a ticket, or it is just enough to add this ticket to each outgoing request as shown above?